# Scrapy can not crawl data down even through set the User-Agent, what's the reason?

Tags: python, scrapy

I am studying Scrapy, I want to scrapy [this site](https://careers.tencent.com/search.html).

In my spider:

```
import scrapy

class TencentHrSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'tencent_hr'
    allowed_domains = ['careers.tencent.com']
    start_urls = ['http://careers.tencent.com/search.html']

    def parse(self, response):

        div_list = response.xpath('//div[@class="recruit-list"]')

        print(div_list)  # there get `[]`, no data in it.
```

When I start crawl, there is no data output. 
why?

I have set the request header User-Agent in `settings.py`:

```
USER_AGENT_LIST=[
'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.139 Safari/537.36'
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2) AppleWebKit/536.3 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/19.0.1062.0 Safari/536.3",
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/536.3 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/19.0.1062.0 Safari/536.3",
    "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; 360SE)",
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/536.3 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/19.0.1061.1 Safari/536.3",
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/536.3 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/19.0.1061.1 Safari/536.3",
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2) AppleWebKit/536.3 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/19.0.1061.0 Safari/536.3",
    "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/535.24 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/19.0.1055.1 Safari/535.24",
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.24 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/19.0.1055.1 Safari/535.24"
]
import random
USER_AGENT = random.choice(USER_AGENT_LIST)
```

---

**Edit - 01**

Is it possible to find the reason? any error log to trace?

---

**EDIT -02**

Why if the data is request from a API by AJAX, the Scrapy can not get data? we know it can down load the whole page, is it possible to run the script like browser?

Comment: If you observe the network requests when visiting the Careers.Tencent.Com, it user another web request through Ajax Call to fetch recruits list. This request is sent to https://careers.tencent.com/tencentcareer/api/post/Query?pageIndex=1&pageSize=10&language=zh-cn&area=us        So, if required, you can send direct request to this and get json feed out of it.

Comment: If you only want to scrape the recruitment data, then you can use rrequests module instead of scrapy as the site provides jso feed for recruits data